# Need to handle ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for stack array, without program ending

Tags: java, exception, data-structures, stack, indexoutofboundsexception

I am doing a pretty simple program, where a user will be prompted to enter up to 80 characters. We need to build our own stack and push each character onto the stack. Then pop and display the characters in reversed order. Thought I was done, but my instructor wants me to do something if a user enters more than 80 characters. Basically, I need to ignore all characters over 80. How would I go about doing this? I have been trying to figure this out, but can't get it. I am sure it will be something simple that I completely missed. Any help, suggestions, are appreciated!

stackUser
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class stackUser {

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter up to 80 characters and I will reverse them: ");
    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = key.nextLine();
    myStack stack = new myStack();

    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){
        char c = input.charAt(i);
        stack.push(c);
        }

    if(stack.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("Stack is empty!");
    }else{
        while(!stack.isEmpty()){
            char rev = stack.pop();
            System.out.print(rev);
        }
     }  
   }
}
```

myStack

```
public class myStack {

private int max = 80;
private char[] Stack = new char[max];
private int top = -1;

public void push(char input){
    top++;
    Stack[top] = input; 
    }

public char pop(){
    char popped = Stack[top];   
    top --;
    return popped;
    }

public boolean isEmpty(){
    boolean empty;
    if(top == -1){
        empty = true;
    }else{
        empty = false;
    }
    return empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is bad idea, you need to check current `top` value with `max` value. Because ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is unchecked exception, and it means that error of developer.

Comment: Where would I want to check these values? I want to ignore every character that goes over `max`. So I have been trying `while(top <= max)` in my `push` method to only push those first 80 onto the stack. But this is not working.

Comment: You can write that:
`public void push(char input) {
        if (top < max - 1) {
            top++;
            Stack[top] = input;
        }
    }`

Comment: That worked perfectly! I was trying something similar and completely forgot to -1 from `max` Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would declare the push method like this to indicate that it will throw an exception if the max is reached:

```
public void push(char input) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException{
    top++;
    Stack[top] = input;
}
```

Then in the main method you can use a try/catch block to handle the exception:

```
try{
    stack.push(c);
}catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
    System.out.println("too much!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A try catch loop around anything that will throw an IndexOutOfBounds

```
try {
        ...code here
}
catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

    ...whatever you want to do in event of exception

}
```